# Extracting the "To:" field of an email header

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a query in which one column is the string of an email header such as this:

```
From: Media Temple user (mt.kb.user@gmail.com)
Subject: article: How to Trace a Email
Date: January 25, 2011 3:30:58 PM PDT
To: user@example.com
Return-Path: <mt.kb.user@gmail.com>
Envelope-To: user@example.com
Delivery-Date: Tue, 25 Jan 2011 15:31:01 -0700
Received: from po-out-1718.google.com ([72.14.252.155]:54907) by cl35.gs01.grid ...
Received: by po-out-1718.google.com with SMTP id y22so795146pof.4 for <user@exa ...
Received: by 10.141.116.17 with SMTP id t17mr3929916rvm.251.1214951458741; Tue,...
Received: by 10.140.188.3 with HTTP; Tue, 25 Jan 2011 15:30:58 -0700 (PDT)
Dkim-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=gmail.com; s=gamma; h=d...
Domainkey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws; d=gmail.com; s=gamma; h=message-id:da...
Message-Id: <c8f49cec0807011530k11196ad4p7cb4b9420f2ae752@mail.gmail.com>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_Part_3927_12044027.1214951...
X-Spam-Status: score=3.7 tests=DNS_FROM_RFC_POST, HTML_00_10, HTML_MESSAGE, HTM...
X-Spam-Level: ***
Message Body: This is a KnowledgeBase article that provides information on how ...
```

I would like to extract only the email address contained within the `'To:'` field, in the example above `user@example.com`.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I would use code. Questions asking for code require that you post what you've tried, and why it didn't work.

Comment: You might want to look at email parser. With a good parser, you don't need to fugire out how to correctly parse it manually.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a split function. I like the version that uses a numbers table, but [there are many alternatives](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings). First, a numbers table with 1,000,000 rows:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @UpperLimit INT;
SET @UpperLimit = 1000000;

WITH n(rn) AS
(
    SELECT TOP (@UpperLimit) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
    FROM sys.all_columns AS s1, sys.all_objects ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
)
SELECT [Number] = rn - 1
INTO dbo.Numbers FROM n
WHERE rn <= @UpperLimit + 1;

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX n ON dbo.Numbers([Number]);
```

Now a generic, inline, table-valued split function, that will turn your delimited string into a set:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitString
(
    @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delim VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
      ( 
        SELECT 
          [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
          CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
        FROM dbo.Numbers WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
        AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
      ) AS x
    );
GO
```

Then it is simple:

```
DECLARE @x NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'From: Media Temple user (mt.kb.user@gmail.com)
Subject: article: How to Trace a Email
Date: January 25, 2011 3:30:58 PM PDT
To: user@example.com
Return-Path: <mt.kb.user@gmail.com>
Envelope-To: user@example.com
...';

SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING(Value, 4, 4000)) 
  FROM dbo.SplitString(@x, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
  WHERE Value LIKE 'To: %@%';
```

Data's in a table? Ok, no problem:

```
DECLARE @a TABLE(id INT, email NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT @a VALUES
(1,N'From: Media Temple user (mt.kb.user@gmail.com)
Subject: article: How to Trace a Email
Date: January 25, 2011 3:30:58 PM PDT
To: user@example.com
Return-Path: <mt.kb.user@gmail.com>
Envelope-To: user@example.com
...'),
(2,N'From: Media Temple user (mt.kb.user@gmail.com)
Subject: article: How to Trace a Email
Date: January 25, 2011 3:30:58 PM PDT
To: differentUser@somewhereelse.com
Return-Path: <mt.kb.user@gmail.com>
Envelope-To: user@example.com
...');

SELECT a.id, LTRIM(SUBSTRING(x.Value, 4, 4000))
FROM @a AS a
CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitString(a.email, CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)) AS x
WHERE x.Value LIKE 'To: %@%';
```

Now, you may have to play with the delimiter - it may be just CHAR(10), or just CHAR(13), or they may be in a different order - not sure, and can't tell from your code what it is...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XML features to split the rows and find what you need;

```
DECLARE @X XML

SELECT @X = CONVERT(XML, '<y><x>' + 
                REPLACE(REPLACE(value, '<', '&lt;'), CHAR(10), '</x><x>') + 
                 '</x></y>')
FROM test

SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM @X.nodes('/y/x') T(c)
WHERE T.c.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)') LIKE 'To: %'
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c57da/2).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Agreed, the arbitrary limit was bad, updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Otherwise it's tidy (though I haven't tested nefariously strategic placement of other problematic characters like `&`). +1

Comment: Can you demonstrate how to use this in a query against the table instead of against a single value extracted from the table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select substring(@s, charindex(char(13)+char(10)+'To: ', @s) + 6, charindex(char(13), @s, charindex(char(13)+char(10)+'To: ', @s)+6) - (charindex(char(13)+char(10)+'To: ', @s)+6))
```

Here's a full test script:

```
declare @s varchar(500)

set @s = 'Date: January 25, 2011 3:30:58 PM PDT
To: user@example.com
Return-Path: <mt.kb.user@gmail.com>
Envelope-To: user@example.com'

select substring(@s, charindex(char(13)+char(10)+'To: ', @s) + 6, charindex(char(13)+char(10), @s, charindex(char(13)+char(10)+'To: ', @s)+6) - (charindex(char(13)+char(10)+'To: ', @s)+6))
```

Note that in a proper email the headers must be separated by CRLF (char(13) + char(10)) according to the spec [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-2.2) and the above code makes the same assumption.

If you have different line endings in your email, you might have to change every occurence of `char(13)+char(10)` to just `char(13)` or `char(10)` . If you do that, remember to also adjust the `+6` to `+5` (because it's one character less).

Comment: It shouldn't because the ``To:`` has to be at the beginning of a line. If there is a "To: in the subject line, it won't be at the beginning (``Subject: `` will).

Comment: Touche' - I did not notice your leading 13+10 (and I didn't down-vote). You should at least warn that 13+10 might not be the cr/lf pair.

Comment: I thought about that but in a proper email the headers must be separated by CRLF: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-2.2

Comment: that's great, but you have no idea how the e-mail was moved from Exchange etc. to wherever it is being stored now. They could have been extracted as text files onto a Unix machine, opened and saved in vi, downloaded to someone's Mac, opened in TextEdit, e-mailed to someone on a PC, opened in Notepad, saved as Unicode, etc. etc.

Comment: Fair point. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It was unintended.

Answer (score 0):

If email address is between first `'To:'` and `'Return-Path:'`, you could use this (**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/23576)**):

```
declare @s nvarchar(max) = 'From: Media Temple user (mt.kb.user@gmail.com)
                        Subject: article: How to Trace a Email
                        Date: January 25, 2011 3:30:58 PM PDT
                        To: user@example.com
                        Return-Path: <mt.kb.user@gmail.com>...'

select substring(@s, charindex('To:',@s)+3, 
             charindex('Return-Path:',@s)- charindex('To:',@s)-3)

--Results
user@example.com
```

**Bit more generic version:** Assuming email address is before the first Return-path

```
;with cte as (
 select reverse(left(@s, charindex('Return-Path:',@s)-1)) rs
)
select reverse(left(rs, charindex(':oT', rs)-1)) 
from cte
```

In a table query, please replace `@s` *with* your `column name`.